# How to specify data type for datatable colums?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

This is my razor. Everything working fine. I just want one thing. 
1. I have date type column I want to defined it's data type as datetime so that shorting work properly. I have added below code that shows my full implementation.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayName("Order No")</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayName("Customer")</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayName("Dealer")</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayName("Status")</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayName("Date")</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (ServiceRequestBycountry service in Model)
     {
       <tr>
         <td>.....</td>
         <td>.....</td>
         <td>.....</td>
         <td>.....</td>
         <td>
           @if (service.CreatedOnUtc != null){
              DateTime servicedate = Convert.ToDateTime(service.CreatedOnUtc);
              @servicedate.ToLocalDate().ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
           }
         </td>
         <td>.....</td>
       </tr>
     }
    </tbody>
  </table>


@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var table = $('#grid').DataTable({
                'aoColumnDefs': [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': -1
                }],
                "order": [[4, "desc"]]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

> I have also added the [JsFidder](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcf7j3wj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var table = $('#grid').DataTable({
                'aoColumnDefs': [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': -1
                }],
                'columnDefs': [
                    { "type": "YOUR_TYPE_HERE", "targets": TARGETED_COLUMN_HERE },
                    /* ... */
                ]
                'order': [[4, "desc"]]
            });
    });
</script>
}
```

More details here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type

Comment: Can you tell me what TARGETED_COLUMN_HERE will be ? index ? and index will start with 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Yes it's the column's index and colmun indexes start with 0. More informations: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

Comment: Seems there is some issue I checked the JsFidder but it's not working with shorting

Comment: What do you mean by shorting ?? Sorting works fine on the fiddle